# Ordering file content in alphabetic order using Python

Tags: sorting, alphabet

In Python, I'm getting a list with emptiness ( i.e.   [  ]  ) in it and testing mechanics indicate that its not sorting the content properly. It fails to pass the sorting of items contained in a file.

Write a program that inputs a text file. The program should print the unique words in the file in alphabetical order.

textFile = input("Input a file name:  ")

with open(textFile) as objects:

```
textReader = objects.readlines()
textReader.sort()
print(textReader)
```

Output:   [  ]

Comment: Try to identify your problem clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the language this needs to be in.
If you would use Ruby it's like this.

```
File.read('input.txt').split(/\W/).uniq.sort
```

The only thing I believe that needs an explanation is the `split(/\W/)` thing.
It's an regular expression (google is your best friend) which means split the text by any non textual characters like spaces and put them in an array.